# relacion de datos en una sola tabla con ORM/Annotation

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine, symfony5

Suponiendo una tabla de cursos como esta:

```
create table courses (
    course_id int primary key,
    course_name char(50)
  );
```

La tabla PRERREQUISITOS se vería así:

```
  create table prerequisites (
    course_id int references courses,
    prereq_course_id int references courses,
    primary key (course_id, prereq_course_id)
  );
```

pero esto no cumple con la generación orgánica de las tablas en el `ORM`:
un ejemplo es que en `annotation` se implementan relaciones con esta sintaxis:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\UserCertification", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $usercertification;
```

y luego se ejecuta el comando:

> php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

y se obtienen relaciones o tablas relacionadas paresidos al siguiente esquema (esto es un ejemplo de como sale al usar el comando `doctrine:schema:update`):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user_certification`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_certification` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `certification` date NOT NULL,
  `expiration` date NOT NULL,
  `evaluation` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `listcertification_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eventcertification_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `usercertification` (`id`,`certification`,`expiration`,`evaluation`),
  KEY `IDX_82B2C025A76ED395` (`user_id`),
  KEY `IDX_82B2C0255586BCD3` (`listcertification_id`),
  KEY `IDX_82B2C0257F4F8556` (`eventcertification_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

si creo manualmente el esquema y luego ejecuto este comando para importar las entidades:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity
```

El resultado es este (no se parece en nada):

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="prereq_course_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 */
private $prereqCourseId;
```

mi duda es ¿cuál es la sintaxis de la relación expresada en las dos primeras tablas usando el ORM / anotación en lugar de usar la herramienta de importación?

***El escenario es el siguiente:*** tengo una tabla con una lista de cursos ... pero algunos de estos cursos tienen niveles 1,2,3; luego, para poder participar en el curso de nivel 2 se requiere un prerrequisito, que sería el nivel anterior (1) ...

1. Primeros auxilios básicos.
2. Primeros auxilios intermedios.
3. Primeros auxilios avanzados.

Pero también tengo otro escenario en la misma tabla:

Un curso de "supervivencia en la selva" puede tener prerrequisitos para cursos como "Primeros Auxilios Intermedios", "Telecomunicaciones Básicas" y "Rapel para rescatadores", en este caso los requisitos no son necesariamente un nivel previo, son simplemente requisitos de cursos anteriores.

Entonces pensé que crearía una tabla para guardar los requisitos previos, pero no entiendo bien cómo debo escribir la anotación del ORM para generar dicha tabla y relación.

Cuando lo genero con import, me trae algo bastante extraño que no se parece a lo que se escribe manualmente (esto es un ejemplo de como sale al usar el comando `doctrine:mapping:import`):

```
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="prereq_course_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
```

lo cual no se parece en nada a la notacion manual onetomany o manytoone

Comment: Normalmente se hace al contrario. Se generan las entidades con las anotaciones, y en estas, las relaciones que se desean establecer. Después con el comando `doctrine:schema:update` traslada toda la configuración de las anotaciones a la base de datos. Al contrario por lo que comentas no va nada bien. Si sigues interesado/a me comentas y le damos un repaso a este tema.

Comment: ya lo resolvi ... tube que hacer un hibrido de doble via ...